# How to use HTML-CSS on outputting data conditionally?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, conditional-statements

I am implementing a unordered list (`<ul><li>...</li></ul>`) inside which to display a link (`<a>...</a>`). In this link tag, other than a title text, I have to *conditionally* * display an image and a short text.

The "complete" output is something as-like the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    +------------------------+
    | +---+  Title           |
    | |   |                  |
    | +---+  Some short text |
    +------------------------+
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, since the above output is conditionally built, it could be that the image or the short text is not displayed. So...

... if the image is not present but the short text is, then the output should be something like

```
 +------------------------+
 | Title                  |
 |                        |
 | Some short text        |
 +------------------------+
```

... if the short text is not present but the image is, then the output should be something like

```
 +------------------------+
 | +---+  Title           |
 | |   |                  |
 | +---+                  |
 +------------------------+
```

... if both image and short text are not present, then the output should be something like

```
 +------------------------+
 | Title                  |
 +------------------------+
```

**I would like to "play" on HTML-CSS tags-properties and not "directly" on the code "behind" / "that generates" that output.** How can I make that?

---

*Note I*: "Basic" structures for each scenario at [jsfiddle.net/zF5Cw/2](http://jsfiddle.net/zF5Cw/2).

*Note II*: For instance, I have problems:

- on properly outputting the `height` of `li` tags when the image is not present: visually, each `li` tag (and the related image) is almost overrode by the previous one;
- on properly outputting the `padding-left` of "Title" and "Some short text" when the image is present and not present;
- ...

---

* Behind the scenes I have a JavaScript code that conditionally adds HTML to the outputting code:

```
var html;

html = "<a>";

if ( image ) { 
  html += "<img>...</img>"
}

if ( short_text ) { 
  html += "Some short text"
}

html += "</a>";

return html;
```

Comment: should  i consider this as my new project ?

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with the generated code i.e. what the finished unordered list looks like after everything has been generated. Make sure to include the 3 scenarios.

Comment: @tw16 - I would like to make that but, for example, I am in trouble in choosing the *correct* / *proper* way to add an image inline with text.

Comment: But you said you didn't want to change the background code that generates the html?! So you have to show us what html we are working with i.e generated. The fiddle will makes it easier to help you.

Comment: @tw16 - If you want the "simple" HTML code (without CSS) related to the question then I can write a fiddle, even if I think its structure is just "intuitive"; the JavaScript code used ("behind the scenes") to build data outputted in that HTML is already explained in the question body.

Comment: As I said in my first comment. I want to see the final html that is used for each scenario. I don't need to see or know how it is generated. I just need to see what the final output is so that I can try to help you style it.

Comment: @tw16 - See "basic" structures for each scenario at http://jsfiddle.net/zF5Cw/2/. Did you mean that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example covers all four of the scenarios you described. Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zF5Cw/3/

```
li {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 300px;
}
img,span{float: left;}
img{margin-right: 10px;}
span{width: 250px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not contain conditional logic that can change your mark-up. You need to use JavaScript to do this.

Comment: I do *not* want to do anything dynamic with HTML/CSS. If the image is present then it should "hold" / "sit in" a fixed space, but when it is not present then nothing is added and the related space is not outputted. How do you'd proceed by using JavaScript?